# How can we have different driver and executor for Spark on Kubernetes on Azure?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

Can I use different machines for Driver and Executor in Spark on Kubernetes? (Azure Kubernetes Service)?

Having two node pools, one for driver using E series machine and another one for Executor using D series machine -> Is this possible?

This is the node pool that I am using currently (Driver and Executor are both Standard_DS15_v2 machines)

[image]

Below is my deployment values.yaml file

```
#
version: 0.0.1
sparkVersion: 3.0.0
image: JAR-name:0.0.1
jar: local:///opt/spark/jars/JAR-name.jar
mainClass: com.company.HelloWorld
fileDependencies: []
environment: test
serviceAccount: my-service-account
imageRegistry: myAcr0.azurecr.io
arguments:
  - "Hello World"
driver:
  cores: 19
  memory: "115g"
executor:
  instances: 125
  cores: 19
  memory: "115g"
hadoopConf:
  "fs.abfss.impl": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.SecureAzureBlobFileSystem"
  "fs.azure.account.key.my_azure_stg_account.dfs.core.windows.net": "KEY_GOES_HERE"
  "fs.file.impl": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocalFileSystem"
hostNetwork: false
imagePullPolicy: Always
userId: 0
nodeSelector: {"agentpool":"unknown"}
```

Comment: Could you assign bounty to me if my answer helps?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can definitely have different nodes for the driver and the executor.
It's actually intended to be executed on different nodes.

[image]

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html

Comment: Robert Reynolds, How can I use the two node pools in my values.yaml config file? I can only use one node pool in Spark on AKS. I know the driver and executors are intended to run on same/different nodes in Spark but how do I do it in Spark on Kubernetes?